# How to port Win32 to .NET without rewriting windows.h?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winapi, pinvoke

I'm porting a legacy WIN32 library to C# in order to compile direclty into your .NET application and simplify debugging, refactorings, etc.

Although small, that library uses plenty of KERNEL32, GDI32 and USER32 APIs. It's an "optimized" image processing tool that modifies images directly in the GDI device context.

The problem is that every time I hit a new API call, I have to create a C# `extern` method declaration, as well as properly described WIN32 structs, and of course constants that it might use. It's a very tedious and error-prone task.

Is there some Nuget or publicly available source code that provides a drop-in porting of major portions of `windows.h`?

I wish I could use [UnsafeNativeMethods.cs from .NET Reference Code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/UnsafeNativeMethods.cs), but that uses `internal` visibility...

Comment: Look at http://pinvoke.net for C# declarations of many frequently used Win32 APIs

Comment: If you use/copy the UnsafeNativeMethods.cs, as specified above, in your assembly, the 'internal' keyword is no problem. The declarations are visible in your assembly, but not to other assemblies. See the 'internal' definition in the MSDN.

Comment: Writing a wrapper for the native implementation using C++/CLI may be a more efficient strategy.

Comment: I've been written interop code for years. windows.h is far from being everything, there are ~4000 h files in the SDK. There's no magic tool to my knowledge, because many API are not technically annotated, so you can only build interop looking at the parameters and reading the doc. You can steal many code from existing assemblies (using decompilation tools) of from existing source, or here on stackoverflow. Another solution is to write .IDL files and build TLB from there that you can use from .NET. BTW, I've written this free online tool for the "constants" issue :-) https://www.magnumdb.com/